# How to make one label value refer another label values in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

This query `label_values(kubelet_runtime_operations_total{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics"}, instance)` gives label as:

`100.130.101.101 100.130.101.102 100.130.101.103`

another different query gives nodes:
`devops-test-srv01 devops-test-srv02 devops-test-srv03`

I tried custom values like this `100.130.101.101 : devops-test-srv01,100.130.101.102 : devops-test-srv02,100.130.101.103 : devops-test-srv03` and used ${label:text} and ${label:value} where I only be using the label as filter and thing is I don't want to do customization in the production everytime

How to map the two labels in query so that I don't have to reconfigure again manualy in the custom values in a new cluster?

Comment: Can you manufacture a query, that will return those metrics within single "line"? Something like `{instance="100.100.100.100", dns_name="test-srv.example.com", someotherlabels="...."}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in both cases you could craft the label name from the last 2 digits of the initial label value:

https://regex101.com/r/rufmke/1

So you might want to use **[label_replace()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace)**:

```
label_replace(kubelet_runtime_operations_total, "instanceNew", "devops-test-srv$1", "instance", ".*(\\d\\d)$")
```

--->

```
kubelet_runtime_operations_total{instance='100.130.101.103', instanceNew='devops-test-srv03'} 1
kubelet_runtime_operations_total{instance='devops-test-srv03', instanceNew='devops-test-srv03'} 2
```

Comment: This answer will probably benefit from explaining how to parse these two labels into variables text and value fields.